# DIY a j-link debugger

Tags: diy, j-link

I want to replicate [THIS](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CJMCU-Jlink-for-SWD-Jlink-3-Wire-for-STM32-on-SWD-Debug/32622682260.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.17.BR5H1W&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10136_10137_10175_10111_10060_10112_10113_10155_10114_10154_438_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10189_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051-10050,searchweb201603_16,ppcSwitch_3&btsid=771753fe-6af9-4167-ae65-283fb6685ac5&algo_expid=df4ca98b-bcd3-4119-b668-48cc5390d200-2&algo_pvid=df4ca98b-bcd3-4119-b668-48cc5390d200) jlink debugger according to my own needs. But I can't find it's schematics and firmware anywhere.

Is illegal to replicate it or distribute it's source? If no, then where can't I find it's schematics and firmware.

Comment: Generally, J-LINK adapters are proprietary products of the SEGGER. The linked product seem to be some kind of reversed Chinese clone. I doubt they will share their finding with you.

Comment: I highly suggest looking for another (maybe something that doesn't look like it's from China) J-LINK module. The Chinese do not like giving out details for their products. I don't know why but it probably has to do with either politics or to secure competition.

Comment: I remember one time I got a cheap little sensor from China for my college project and it came with no details at all. I had to define the characters of this sensor on my own as well a schematic of PCB layout of this sensor on my own.

Answer (score 1):

The J-Link hardware design and firmware is proprietary to [Segger](https://www.segger.com/). Some Chinese manufacturers seem to have managed to copy it to some degree or another, but the methods they've used are not public.

There is no legitimate way to make your own J-Link programmer. If you want to build your own JTAG debugger, designs and firmware are freely available for the [Black Magic Probe](https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic).

Comment: Or use an FT2232H/FT4232H or any of the many other relatively open solutions.